# How to limit database flushing to disk?

Tags: c++, sqlite

I am using sqlite database in my arm9 embedded linux platform. I want to reduce writes to disk database because my disk is a flash memory and it needs minimum write cycles. So I tried to increment SQLITE_DEFAULT_CACHE_SIZE as 5000. My objective was to write data to cache and when the cache is filled, automatically flush to disk. But by incrementing SQLITE_DEFAULT_CACHE_SIZE, I can't confirm whether this is working or not. I am not seeing any changes in the operations! Is my way correct? Can anybody give me some suggestions?
Thanks 
Aneesh

Comment: I am not sure if I understand your requirement. Usually databases are used to ensure transactional guarantees. To do that the database needs to write to the disk. If you have state changes that are not important why do you bother to update the database? You could just keep the state changes in memory and only update the database when you must persist your changes. In that case hitting the disk is unavoidable by design,

Comment: Usually does not mean always.   sqlite gets used in lots of exotic environments as a temporary storage mechanism.  Caches of remote data on a phone, for example - if the cache goes away, it can always be rebuilt, it's just slower.  In that case, I want it to be fast, and I want to know if it's corrupted.  But corruption is OK, as long as I know that my store is invalid.  I can throw it away occasionally.

Answer (score 3):

SQLite to be ACID db flushes with every commit OR with every insert/delete/update not wrapped with transaction. Use transactions for grouping operations OR turn OFF ACIDity and set PRAGMA synchronous=OFF.

"PRAGMA synchronous = OFF" and SQLite won't flush data at all (effectively leaving that to OS Cache)

SQLITE_DEFAULT_CACHE_SIZE is ONLY for size of cache. And cache is used ONLY for reading data.

There is another option - you can implement own VFS layer and prevent page saving at all before your own buffer will be full. http://www.sqlite.org/c3ref/vfs.html

But I'm sure that sync=off (or much better to use transactions) will do the job good enough (while having a good chance to corrupt your db in case power failures or hard reset for sync=off).

Another hint is to place JOURNAL in memory or turn it off completely. Again - it's turning off acidity, but that also removes some disk touches.

Comment: I agree; transaction structure is probably where the greatest benefit could be found.

Answer (score 2):

The latest [SQLite has a feature for backing up hot databases](http://www.sqlite.org/c3ref/backup_finish.html) it's still experimental, but my recommendation would be to use an on Memory Database and merge it with the Disk database when you think is appropriate.

Comment: Yes Robert you are Right,But the Problem is i have to flush the Database periodically,that seems to be too risky.My intention is whether Sqlite is supporting any kind of default flushing based on  Cache full?
i have done some experiments based on the above scenario by setting 
PRAGMA journal_mode=MEMORY ,PRAGMA SQLITE_DEFAULT_CACHE_SIZE=5000 and PRAGMA synchronous=FULL,
But the flushing rate seems to be similar on cache size of 2000(default) and 5000.this makes me wonder.please help ?

Comment: Unfortunately those options won't affect the rate to which it'll hit the drive

Comment: First of all thanks for your valuble suggestions,
you are telling that,cache full can not be used as a criteria for flushing the data from Ram to disk file? if it have, then my problem may solve with out any risk factor.do you have any other option to suggest?
Advanced thanks,
Aneesh

Comment: Although it's not specific to SQLite, I'll assume you have enough RAM, because you're willing to cache, so you can have your own cache, store transactions and once you reach say 100 transactions, or 1 minute goes by, you flush all transactions. But you'll need to store the commands in an array (using RAM)

Answer (score 0):

Ok Neil .If the "SQLite is using a form of write-through caching" then  on the cache overflow, it will try to flush the Data to some temporary file or disk file .This is the Same point i am trying to experiment by by enalrging the cache size and thus acquire control over flushing rate .but it is not happening.please reply.

Comment: Firstly, you should probably modify your original question to ask this. Secondly, write-through cacheing means that all writes are immediately commited to disk, but the data that was written is also held in the cache. Thus cache size has little or no effect on write-to-disk frequency. Like I said, I can't be 100% sure that this is happening - take a look at the code yourself.

Answer (score -2):

You have the source code to SQLite - why not simply instrument it to record the information you are interested in.

Comment: At some point in the SQLite code, the decision is made to flush the cache - add a counter and a of some kind there to record the write. You can then examine the counter to extract stats of how frequently flushing is happening.

Comment: @robert strange - I felt the same about your answer.

Comment: Hi,
But the Problem is i have to flush the Database periodically,that seems to be too risky.My intention is whether Sqlite is supporting any kind of default flushing based on Cache full? i have done some experiments based on the above scenario by setting PRAGMA journal_mode=MEMORY ,PRAGMA SQLITE_DEFAULT_CACHE_SIZE=5000 and PRAGMA synchronous=FULL, But the flushing rate seems to be similar on cache size of 2000(default) and 5000.this makes me wonder.please help ?

Comment: @Neil: The question isn't about recording/metrics, its about reducing the frequency with which SQLite hits the drive. But ok, with the explanation your answer is at least understandable. Before it seemed like you came out of the blue.

Comment: @aneesh - are you trying to confirm that changing the cache size alters the rate of flushing, which is how I read your question. If not, please edit your question to make it clearer.

Comment: Exactly.I am doing the same.But i change the cache size also the same behavior is happening

Comment: @ahneesh I just took a cursory look at the code and it seems to me that SQLite is using a form of write-through cacheing, in which case the cache size will make little difference to write frequency. I could easily be wrong on this though.